# Using a Parameter value in an Oracle case statement

Tags: oracle, case

I am trying to pass a parameter value in my case statement as below

```
CASE WHEN b.Billing_code IN  ('Audio_And_Others') THEN [:Audio_Comm_Percentage] END AS Commission_Rate
```

My Parameter being [:Audio_Comm_Percentage] and will be set as a decimal number e.g. 0.12 or 0.05 etc.

I am getting a "missing expression" message when I run this

Comment: Why you parameter is enclosed in the brackets?

Comment: Hi Popeye.  I am using the Oracle SQL Developer product,(I normally write code in MS SQL) so this is how I have passed parameters into my code using [ ]  on this product ? If there is a better way, I am open to suggestions

Comment: if you remove entire parameter from this case expression, then is it working properly? 2. IF you just remove the brackets from parameter ans use :parameter then is it working fine?

Comment: Hi Popeye. My bad, sorry, I am using the wrong brackets [ ]   should be ()  My eye sight needs testing